# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Good afternoon everyone, I am facing this problem when creating my list in recyclerview.
My API response has a list, and within that list is a list of Images, which I need to access to get the image link and upload it to my imageview.

**My API Response:**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "KCLSwV5",
        "title": "I wake up when i have my morning coffee",
        "description": null,
        "images": [
            {
                "id": "k47zXXl",
                "title": null,
                "link": "https://i.imgur.com/k47zXXl.jpg"
            }
        ]

    }
    ]
}
```

So I created my model this way.

```
public class Data implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;

@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;

@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<Images> images = null;


//Getters and Setters
public List<Images> getImages() { return images; }

public void setImages(List<Images> images) { this.images = images; }
```

**The error logs:**

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.allan.galleryapp.adapter.ListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.java:39)
    at com.example.allan.galleryapp.adapter.ListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.java:18)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:641)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6752)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6752)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6752)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6752)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6752)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:755)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23187)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1890)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1494)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7288)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

logs say error is happening on my adapter in onBindViewHolder method.

**My adapter:**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Data> dataList;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListAdapter.ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ListAdapter.ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListAdapter.ListViewHolder listViewHolder, int i) {

    String image = dataList.get(i).getImages().get(i).getLink(); //LINE 39 I believe the error is here, but I don't know how to solve it.


    Glide.with(context)
            .load(image)
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.load))
            .into(listViewHolder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
}
```

I will be grateful if anyone can help me.

Cheers.

Comment: `dataList.get(i).getImages().get(i).getLink()` – You're using `i` to get an element from both `dataList` and `dataList.get(i).getImages()`. That makes sense for `dataList`, since the `Adapter`'s count is determined by `dataList.size()`, but it doesn't make sense for `dataList.get(i).getImages()`. Follow? I'm not sure what you're trying to retrieve there, but that Exception is likely thrown when it tries to bind a position that is greater than the maximum index in `dataList.get(i).getImages()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing error use this model, use this website to make model.
[Jsontopojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
  public class Example {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<Image> images = null;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public List<Image> getImages() {
return images;
}

public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
this.images = images;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Image.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Image {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private Object title;
@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Object getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(Object title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer made me think and I managed to solve the problem.